# Resetting a mysql column to a base value every 1 month

Tags: mysql

I have a column called defaultHours in my table, and the amount in this box is different depending on which package they purchased (ex. 5, 10, 15). When the person purchases a package, it will insert their ID, number of defaultHours (depending on package), and a timestamp. The user can spend their defaultHours up to 0, then have to purchase extra hours which is another column.

What I want to do is have the number of defaultHours go back to the original amount (5, 10, 15, etc.) exactly 1 month of their original time stamp, regardless of how much they used or didn't use.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Illustrate what you would like to achieve with an example.

Comment: @sasha Example: Someone purchases a plan from us, so they receive 5 defaultHours (which are development hours for them) per month, they can use up to 5 hours each month for FREE. After 1 month of the original timestamp, their defaultHours will go back to 5, regardless of how many they used. I want to be able to have the defaultHours column updated for each and every user. I could go about this many ways, I just want to konw the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do it:

```
UPDATE tbl SET defaultHours = 5 
WHERE ts >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
  AND ts < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

?

Comment: Thank you so much, this did it!